# How to declare child resources in Tastypie?

Tags: python, django, api, rest, tastypie

I have this `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()

class Note(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
```

And this `api.py`:

```
import tastypie
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.api import Api
from main.models import Item, Note

class ItemResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'items'
        queryset = Item.objects.all()

class NoteResource(ModelResource):
    items = tastypie.fields.ToManyField(ItemResource, 'items', full=True)

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'notes'
        queryset = Note.objects.all()

api = Api(api_name='v1')
api.register(NoteResource())
```

I want the only endpoint to items be:

`/api/v1/notes/4/items`

`/api/v1/notes/4/items/2`

And no `/api/v1/items/?note=4`

I've been reading Tastypie documentation and i didn't found any info on this.

[This](http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.org/en/latest/urls.html#url-structure) document recommends the URL form i post here.

**How can i accomplish this?**

Comment: You might want to check out http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: @orokusaki OK, i've been reading a lot of that. It looks way better than Tastypie. Can you point me in the right direction on doing this with restframework?

Comment: I just added an answer with more info for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) (posterity, see comments on OP), child resources are declared as follows (simple example):

```
class AddressSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    A serializer for ``Address``.
    """
    class Meta(object):
        model = Address


class OrderSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    A serializer for ``Order``.
    """
    address = AddressSerializer()

    class Meta(object):
        model = Order
```

To get started, I highly recommend simply following [this tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart#serializers). It will get you 100% of what you need, in terms of customizing your URLs, customizing your serialized output, etc.

Tasty pie is a great project, and the creator, Daniel Lindsley, is a really smart guy (I worked with him for a short while), but just like every other great project, somebody came along and blew our socks off with something new that has [learned from the good and bad parts of the existing framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_on_the_shoulders_of_giants).